ErrorOr is giving error when returning IActionResult from API
I am using ErrorOr (https://github.com/amantinband/error-or) library to return responses from my API. However, when I return response from my API method, I get this error:

This is my code:
[HttpPost("token", Name = "GenerateToken")]
[ProducesResponseType<GenerateToken.Response>((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateToken(GenerateToken.Command command)
{
    var response = await mediator.Send(command);

    return await response.MatchAsync(
        value => Ok(value),
        errors => BadRequest(errors));
}

What I am doing wrong here? Any help will be appreciated.

Could you please tell me what's the  response type for this var response = await mediator.Send(command); and I suggest you could try this :   return await response.MatchAsync(
value => Task.FromResult(Ok(value)),
errors => Task.FromResult(BadRequest(errors)));

The return type from Send is "ErrorOr". I guess the solution you provided is working but it looks so weird like not clean. Do you know why this is happening at first place?

This is related how MatchAsync return

If I don't use the Asyn version, any work around for that?

I don't get your point, normally, we suggest using the async.

This is slightly off-topic, but I'd also suggest taking a look at the more general-purpose and widely used OneOf library for discriminated unions.

As was pointed out in the comments, your MatchAsync method closures need to return a Task of TValue. On top of that, you're returning OkOjectResult type in the onValue closure, and a BadRequestObjectResult type in the onError closure. So, the MatchAsync method can't infer what the TValue shape is supposed to be.
Since you aren't doing anything async in your Match closures, you can just use the non Async Match and avoid the Task wrapped return value, but your problem is still the same; Match doesn't know that you want to return through the IActionResult interface. So you must either explicitly cast each closure (or just one of the closures) return value to an IActionResult so that Match can infer the TValue type
return response.Match(
            value => (IActionResult)Ok(value),
            errors => (IActionResult)BadRequest(errors));

Or, explicitly declare the generic type of IActionResult on the method call
return response.Match<IActionResult>(
            Ok,
            BadRequest);

If it is really bothering you to declare the IActionResult as the generic, you can tuck it away in an extension method that will automatically deal with this:
ErrorOrAspNetCoreExtensions:
namespace ErrorOr.AspNetCore;

public static class ErrorOrAspNetCoreExtensions
{
    public static IActionResult Match<T>(this ErrorOr<T> value, Func<T, IActionResult> onValue, Func<List<Error>, IActionResult> onError)
    {
        return value.Match(onValue, onError);
    }
}

now you can route calls into your extension method with all the typing taken care of under the hood:
using ErrorOr.AspNetCore;
//...other usings

[HttpPost("token", Name = "GenerateToken")]
[ProducesResponseType<GenerateToken.Response>((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateToken(GenerateToken.Command command)
{
    var response = await mediator.Send(command);

    return response.Match(
            Ok,
            BadRequest);
}


I would strongly recommend avoiding IActionResult whenever you know the type of the response. Using ActionResult<T> instead gives you a lot more compile-time protection:
[HttpPost("token", Name = "GenerateToken")]
public async Task<ActionResult<GenerateToken.Response>> GenerateToken(GenerateToken.Command command)
{
    var response = await mediator.Send(command);

    return await response.MatchAsync(
        value => Ok(value),
        errors => BadRequest(errors));
}

This will surface the error more clearly to you, as the return won't match. You can then explicitly pass in the result type on the Match call:
[HttpPost("token", Name = "GenerateToken")]
public async Task<ActionResult<GenerateToken.Response>> GenerateToken(GenerateToken.Command command)
{
    var response = await mediator.Send(command);

    return response.Match<ActionResult<GenerateToken.Response>>(
        value => value,
        errors => BadRequest(errors));
}

Since you are not performing any async operation in the Match lambdas, you can just use the sync version.
Special attention to the lack of Ok(...) in that version, since ActionResult<T> automatically converts from the value and stores the value type in the produced result object.
Also note that relying on the strongly typed ActionResult<T> also allows you to drop the [ProducesResponseType] attribute since now the type can be inferred and included in the API schema automatically.

good call on the ActionResult<T>, something my answer lacks
